# Which among the following are non-finite verbs?

Tags: grammar

In the conversation below which verbs are non-finite?

> Cook: What **shall** I **cook** for dinner tonight, sir?
>   Master: **Prepare** some sweets, I **am expecting** two guests.
>   Cook: Fine, sir.
>   Master: Also **make** some fruit salad.
>   Cook: Yes, sir.

There are 6 verbs and I'm bit confused.  I think that *shall* and *am* are finite verbs, and the rest are non-finite, but I don't understand why.  I read some material too on the topic but it is of no help.

I want to know what characteristics these verbs have which makes them non-finite.

Comment: In a sentence or two, what are some characteristics of a "finite" verb?  What are the five verbs that you see in the example dialog?  Which verbs seem to be "finite" to you?  Which ones don't seem to be finite to you?

Comment: Did you mean to say "a none finite verb"?  Or perhaps you meant "a non-finite verb" or "an infinitive verb"?

Comment: "Which one" doesn't make sense here.  There are four non-finite and two finite verbs in this example.

Comment: 'Shall'  and. 'am'. are finite verbs. The remaining verbs as 'expecting, make, and prepare I want to know which characteristic of them make them non finite.

Comment: @AltafJahangir Very good, but you left out the sixth verb, *cook*.

Comment: I mean non-finite verbs

Answer (score 1):

"Cook" and "expecting" are non-finite forms, because they are governed by "will" and "am" respectively. However, I don't think that's a useful analysis: better to regard "will cook" and "am expecting" as (compound) finite forms.

"Prepare" and "make" are imperative. I would regard imperatives as finite, but that depends which grammatical theory you choose to follow.